# In Drupal Commerce how do you auto login an anonymous user that has completed checkout?

Tags: 7, users, commerce

I have Drupal 7 Commerce core installed and configured manually. Not kickstart.

Currently after completing a Commerce checkout (Paypal Express) with an anonymous user, I get redirected back to the "Checkout Complete" page. The page gives a link to **Review My Order**, but it asks for login details which I do not have since it was an anonymous checkout.

Is there a way to auto login the user after the Successful Checkout?

Comment: It doesn't seem worthwhile to copy-paste the entire process, but there's detailed instructions [here](http://s1l.org/automatic-user-login-anonymous-checkout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short summary to the link Clive posted in case if it ever gets deleted on the interwebs:

http://s1l.org/automatic-user-login-anonymous-checkout

Step 1 - Make sure Anonymous checkout is checked on. (**Permissions > Access Checkout**)

Step 2 - Make sure Commerce Immediate Login module is enabled: http://drupal.org/sandbox/simongeorges/1676742

Step 3 - Add a User Login Action to the default Commerce "Create new account for anonymous order" Rule (**Configuration -> Workflow ->Rules**)

--- ***rules/reaction/manage/Create a new account for an anonymous order***

Step 4 - Click Add action > Login User (under system) > type "account-created" > **SAVE**

Step 5 - TEST!

Comment: **duckx** Your answer + [this](https://drupal.org/project/nocurrent_pass) module make great functional for Drupal site))

Comment: Hi oneng, can you explain your recipe? Also if the module makes the password optional, does it generate a random password for the user? And how would they login then if the password is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest may be to edit the checkout completion text in Store > Configuration > Checkout and remove the relevant link.

A user account is created for the anonymous order after checkout by Commerce.

The user gets emailed a login link and they can check their order details directly by clicking a link in the email there.

This way, you can verify their email address prior to login.

Answer (score 0):

These days, a module with an official release is available as an alternative to sandbox project in your own answer. I.e the [Commerce Checkout Complete Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_complete_registration) module. Some more details about it (from its project page):

> About:
>
> It's about having a way to choose or not, for the Guest customer, if (s)he wants to register.
>
> - Create new pane for the "Complete" checkout page.
> - This pane has 3 settings (for now) : password required (boolean), account creation email notification (boolean) and the text to be displayed for this pane form.
> - The pane will contain a button form + extra elements as the settings say.
> - On this pane form submission:
>
>   - an user account will be created and set as the current user;
>   - the order will be assigned to the new user;
>   - a Rule event will be invoked (with order and user objects);
>   - the user will be redirected to its order history page.
>
> Extra:
>
> This module could be used togheter with Anonymous checkout option of the [Commerce Checkout Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect) module.